# Dropbox API Javascript - uploadFile() results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload a file using the Dropbox API. I am using React for the front end where I take the file from an HTML input element and store in the react state. After clicking a button, the file should be sent using the uploadfile() method in the Dropbox API. Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {Dropbox} from 'dropbox'

export default function Home() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const fileHandler = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  const uploadFile = () => {
    const UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT = 150 * 1024 * 1024;
      var ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.DROPBOX_TOKEN;
      var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
      
      console.log(file);

      if (file.size < UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) { // File is smaller than 150 Mb - use filesUpload API
        console.log('Attempting to upload file');
        dbx.filesUpload({path: '/' + file.name, contents: file})
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Upload video</h1>
        
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={fileHandler}/>
          <button onClick={uploadFile}>Submit</button>
        </div>

      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I literally took the code from their GitHub example, so I can't figure out why the request is bad. I have checked the file sent is correct, and that the Access Token is correct too.

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding request info from dev tools for reference.

Request Headers
[image: request headers]

Comment: The 400 response often contains an explanation of what went wrong (e.g. how the request was malformed). What does the full response look like?

Comment: I don't get a response, the method throws an error which says "DropboxResponseError: Response failed with a 400 code
    at Dropbox-sdk.min.js:1". That's the thing that I found the most frustrating that I did not get much info from the error message.

Comment: Oh I see. What about the request, what does that look like? You can view it from the browser's Dev tools (usually F12).

Comment: I added a screenshot of the request taken from dev tools for reference.

Comment: And what's in the Response tab there?

Comment: There might be some hints in this issue thread ~ https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/662

Comment: The response tab just says "Failed to load response data". EDIT: On Firefox it does give me a response message, looks like there are some permissions not set up with my app. I'll look into that.

Comment: It turns out I just needed to set up permissions for the app on Dropbox. Thank you guys for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome was not loading the response message on dev tools, so I tried on Firefox. There, I found out that my problem was that permissions were not set up in the application on Dropbox. After setting up the permissions and regenerating a new access token it worked fine.